# DexGuard/Proguard obfuscate annotation values

Tags: annotations, proguard, dexguard

I use **Dagger2**. I have next code:

```
@Provides
@Named("Server API")
String getApiUrl(){}
```

And consuming code:

```
public class Client {
   @Inject
   Client(@Named("Server API") url){}
}
```

Will **Dexguard**/**Proguard** obfuscate strings values in annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String Values in Annotations can not be obfuscated by DexGuard.

Comment: To hide this information in the class you could try class encryption, using the `-encryptclasses` directive of DexGuard.